# Shifting each clock event and clock =1 ( VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, clock, bit-shift

This code shifts `n1` and `n2` on every `clk'event and clk=1` in condition of `sh=1` and `su=0`. The problem is that shifting happens for the first rising edge and could not happen again for the next rising edges, anyone have idea how to make it continuous shifting? thanks.

```
ENTITY register_divider IS
  port( st , clk :in std_logic ; 
    num : in std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);

    qu : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    re : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    n1r : out std_logic_vector ( 8 downto 0 );
    counter : in std_logic_vector ( 3 downto 0);
    Sh, su, Ld: in std_logic ;
    n1c: in std_logic_vector ( 8 downto 0 )
  );
END ENTITY register_divider;

--
ARCHITECTURE rtl OF register_divider IS
BEGIN  

    process(clk)
        variable n1 : std_logic_vector ( 8 downto 0);
        variable n2 : std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0) ;
    begin

        n2 := num(7 downto 0);
        n1 := '0' & num(15 downto 8); 

        if (clk'event and clk = '1' ) then
             n1r <= n1 ; 
             if ( sh='1' and su = '0') then 
                n1 := n1(7 downto 0) & n2(7);
                n2 := n2(6 downto 0) & '0';
             end if ;

             if  ( su = '1' and su = '1') then 
                n2(0) := '1';
                n1 := n1c ;
             end if ; 
        end if ; 

        qu <= n2 ;
        re <= n1(7 downto 0);
    end process;
 END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

Comment: It does shift every clock cycle. Problem is, it also reloads the original inputs every clock cycle first. You need to figure out a way to load the inputs on something like a "load" command instead of every cycle.

Comment: yes , thanks i notice that now but i don't have idea how to solve that problem do u have any idea ?

Comment: You would need something like a "load" input to signal when you need to load new values.

Comment: There are a few other problems with your code, including unused signals and incomplete sensitivity lists. http://www.sigasi.com/sites/www.sigasi.com/files/SO/SO_27818175.html

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818175/shifting-each-clock-event-and-clock-1-vhdl#comment44042429_27818175) by Brian, your code is shifting as you desire, however, the problem is that it is also loading/setting the register every cycle as well, essentially undoing what you want.  Instead of loading/setting the registers `n1` and `n2` every cycle (unconditionally), you need to include a condition to load them when the appropriate signal is asserted (`Ld` perhaps?)